# How to change all text colour to default colour (Black for Text, Grey for Hint) instead of white

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, textview

Currently all my text and hint colour by default is all white, although I do ok when I'm able to change them in `xml` file, but certain stuff like `TextInputLayout` text counter doesn't allow colour change

below are my `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#5CCDCC</color>
```

below are my `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/GreenishBlue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

[image: When The background is black, the text counter is visible]

[image: When The background is white]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AndroidManifest` was modified like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

And the file `res/values/styles.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item> //black color for text
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#939393</item> //Gray color for hint
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Anyway is my style causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding below code to your existing `AppTheme` will change default text color in controls where text color is not set inline in xml, using different style or dynamically.

```
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>     
<item name="android:textColorHint">#666666</item>
```